# My Pandas Dataframe Cutoff Breaks at a Certain Bottom Bound?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have Pandas dataframe "ALL" and I'm trying to isolate rows with 'Age' column values between 4mil and 6mil. While 3.5mil as a bottom cutoff works fine, slightly increasing it generates an empty list. Is this expected behavior?

`e1 = ALL.drop(ALL[((ALL['age']) >= 6000000) | ((ALL['age']) < 3500000)].index)`

The above code should drop all rows with ages not between 3.5 and 6 million, and generates the expected result, a chart of form

| L | T | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.088212 | 3031.0 | 3.500934e+06 |
| ... | interstitial values cropped for legibility | ... |
| 0.064501 | 3153.0 | 5.106847e+06 |

However, when I try changing the bottom cutoff to anything higher than 3500000, even 3600000, it gives no results whatsoever.

`e1 = ALL.drop(ALL[((ALL['age']) >= 6000000) | ((ALL['age']) < 3600000)].index)`

| L | T | age |
| --- | --- | --- |

Has this happened to anyone before? Trying to separate it into two lines--one cropping high, then cropping the cropped dataframe from below--has the same error. There are clearly results between 3.6m and 6m, for example, 4.12e6 or 5.1e6, that should appear in both, but don't.

Comment: I don't find anything wrong in code. Can you check the datatype of age column. I think that is creating the problem

Comment: `ALL[((ALL['age']>= 3600000)| ALL['age']<=6000000)]` Can you try this instead of drop the rows and all